# Best way to reuse variables in different Sinatra Routes

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have an instance variable in a Sinatra route that I want to use in two different routes:

```
get '/home/:name' do
    @name = params[:name]
    erb :home
end


get '/define' do
    user = User.create(name: @name)
    erb :define
end
```

My application doesn't allow me to use `@name` in a different route. What is the best way to make @name reusable in other routes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sinatra with a persistent variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443718/sinatra-with-a-persistent-variable)

Comment: Use sessions or class variables. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443718/sinatra-with-a-persistent-variable) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135854/sinatra-variable-scope).